# Batch file for deleting contents of folder once a week EXCEPT for a .bat file within the folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, script

I have seen a lot of variations of my situation but can't find one I'm comfortable with (very inexperienced). Basically I have a folder (E:\Downloads) that folders get added to and also contains a batch file (Extractor.bat). I would like to, once a week, delete all folders and files from within E:\Downloads but NEVER delete Extractor.bat. Thanks for any help on this! (The once a week part isn't necessary in the script, I know I can just set a windows task to run the bat file on specified days).

Windows 10

Comment: Two ideas: 1)Move/copy the batch file within the script itself, delete all files then move back `move %~dp0 ..\ del *.* move ..\%~dp0 .\ ` 2)consider using Powershell which has an exclusion switch: `Remove-Item -Path *  -Exclude $PSCommandPath`

Answer (score 2):

See the `Set DEBUG=echo` line?

Disable this line with `REM` or `::` when you are sure that it is doing what you want it to do.  This script is harmless while it exists.. not so much if you remove it.

The `if /i not "%DownloadsDir%" == "%CD%"` line comes from being stupid and blowing away all of my files in the wrong directory when I was younger and dumber.

Also.. you could change the `cd /d` to `pushd` and put a `popd` at the bottom if you are running this within cmd.exe and it messes up your current path.

```
@echo off
SetLocal
Set DEBUG=echo

Set DownloadsDir=E:\Downloads

cd /d %DownloadsDir%
if /i not "%DownloadsDir%" == "%CD%" echo Bad directory! && goto :EOF

for /F "delims=" %%d in ('dir /ad /b') do %DEBUG% rd /s /q "%%d"
for %%f in (*.*) do if /i not "%%f"=="Extractor.bat" %DEBUG% del /F /Q "%%f"

EndLocal
```

Comment: This worked to perfection, thank you very much!!

Comment: Please feel free to mark this as the correct answer then ;)  And you are very welcome.